# jquery + formatting colours in a cell in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

if i do `console.log(row);`

I get the following:
 
`<tr role="row" class="even"><td>DeviceName2</td><td>85%</td><td class="sorting_1">85%</td><td>74%</td><td>70%</td></tr>`

I can then do this:  `$(row).css("background", "orange");`

to get the following from a `console.log(row);`:

`<tr role="row" class="even" style="background: orange;"><td>DeviceName2</td><td>85%</td><td class="sorting_1">85%</td><td>74%</td><td>70%</td></tr>`

what I want to do is create a traffic like effect of green, orange, red depending on the value in he `td`. How do I do this? Is there an environment where I can
test this till i get it right as I am a novice, [jsfiddle maybe](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/g2qu4mqu/)

This is what i am thinking although i am a long way off:

`$(row).("td")("background", (n < 2) ? "green" : "orange");`

Answer (score 0):

I think best way to go would be to add class to your `td` element based on value, and having css description to set the background based on class value. Example:

HTML (Sample table)

```html
<table id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Remark</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Apple</td>
        <td class='valCell'>25</td>
        <td>OK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Orange</td>
        <td class='valCell'>35</td>
        <td>Still OK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Banana</td>
        <td class='valCell'>80</td>
        <td>High</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS (Add class based on value)

```js
$('#mytable .valCell').each(function() {
  if ($(this).html() < 50) {
    $(this).addClass('normal');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('high')
  }
});
```

CSS (Add backgroup-color based on class)

```css
#mytable td.high{
    background-color:#FF9966;
}

#mytable td.normal{
    background-color:#66FF99;
}
```

See example <kbd>[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/nMhmS/1072/)</kbd>